# Ubuntu on XPS13 9333... Want to add Windows 8.1

Tags: dual-boot, windows, dell, xps

When I bought my XPS13 9333 I got angry with Windows, wiped it, and installed Ubuntu.  My son now wants Windows for gaming (thanks Lego World!).  I don't know my product key (but expect I can get it from Dell) and need a detailed "how to" on partitioning and installing Windows.  I think I wiped it so clean that I can't restore it to factory settings and don't have any recovery disks (may need to order from Dell).  Any help is appreciated! /M

Answer (score 0):

I don't have ALL of your answers, but I know I have enough to save you considerable time, anguish, and probably money.

First I must caution you that microsoft does not play well with other operating systems.  It is difficult enough to set up a dual boot these days when Windows is already on the drive, but if you try adding windows to a computer which already has Ubuntu on it, there is a high probability that windows will wipe the drive despite your best efforts.  Fortunately I have a relatively easy solution which could easily cost you under $50.

To ensure windows doesn't wipe your Ubuntu installation, REMOVE YOUR HARD DRIVE.  Replace the hard drive with a nice blank one, and install Windows on that.  Move your old hard drive into a well cooled external usb case and then you can boot that (or most other computers) to your rescued ubuntu installation.

If for any reason you are hesitant to remove the physical drive, such as a warranty for example I can advise you how to clone your ubuntu onto an external drive before you attempt installing windows.  Both solutions are equally valid.  I remove hard drives all the time, so that's the solution that occurs first to me.

If I recall correctly, Microsoft now offers the installable files as a free download, so you don't need to buy disks, and the files are up to date, rather like ubuntu distros.